# How to pause a specific kafka consumer thread when concurrency is set to more than 1?

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka 2.2.8 and setting concurrency to 2 as shown below and trying to understand how do i pause an consumer thread/instance when particular condition is met.

```
@KafkaListener(id = "myConsumerId", topics = "myTopic", concurrency=2)
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }
```

Now, I've two questions.

1. Would my consumer span two different poll threads  to poll the records?
2. If i'm setting an id to the consumer as shown above. How can i pause a specific consumer thread (with concurrency set to more than 1).

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(id)` method to get a reference to the container.

Cast it to a `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` and call `getContainers()` to get a list of the child `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`s; you can then pause/resume them individually.

You can determine which topics/partitions each one has using `getAssignedPartitions()`.

Comment: Thanks @Gary for the details, I'll try this.