# How to pause/stop a consumer thread after consuming a pre-defined no of records when concurrency is set to more than 1?

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka 2.2.8 and setting concurrency to 5 as shown below and trying to understand how can i stop or pause a consumer instance/thread to stop after consuming a pre-defined no of records. The idea behind this requirement is to see if we can evenly distribute the message consumption across all the consumer threads/instances when using concurrency.

For example, if i've produced 50k messages onto a topic and and have a consumer as shown below with concurrency set to '5', can i stop/pause the consumer threads after they consumed 10k records each?

```
@KafkaListener(id = "myConsumerId", topics = "myTopic", concurrency=5)
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }
```

Here is my ThreadLocal var

```
public static ThreadLocal<Integer> consumedMessages = new ThreadLocal<Integer>() { @Override protected Integer initialValue() { return Integer.valueOf(0); } };
```

Here is my logic in the consumer to increment the counter and pause the consumer.

```
int messageCount = 10000;

@KafkaListener(id = "myConsumerId", topics = "myTopic", concurrency=5)
        public void listen(String in) {
            System.out.println(in);

            ConsumerPerfTestingConstants.consumedMessages.set(ConsumerPerfTestingConstants.consumedMessages.get() .intValue() + 1); 
            if (ConsumerPerfTestingConstants.consumedMessages.get() == messageCount) { 
                System.out.println("ATTENTION! ATTENTION! ATTENTION! Consumer Finished processing "+messageCount+" messages"); 

                ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer concurrentMsgLstnrCntnr = (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer) this.registry.getListenerContainer("myConsumerId"); 

                if (ConsumerPerfTestingConstants.mtpConsumerConsumedMessages.get() == messageCount && concurrentMsgLstnrCntnr != null) 
                    concurrentMsgLstnrCntnr.pause();
            }
        }



    if (concurrentMsgLstnrCntnr != null) {
    List<KafkaMessageListenerContainer> list = concurrentMsgLstnrCntnr.getContainers();
    List<ConsumerMetrics> consumerMetricsList = new ArrayList<>();

    list.forEach(childContainer -> {
        // ConsumerMetrics is my custom bean
        ConsumerMetrics consumerMetrics = new ConsumerMetrics();

        logger.logDebug(String.format("Child Listener Id is %s and assigned partitions are %s ",
                childContainer.getListenerId(),
                childContainer.getAssignedPartitions()), this.getClass());

        // This method is to populated the metrics
        populateAndPrintContainerMetrics(childContainer.metrics(), consumerMetrics);

        if (!consumerMetrics.getRecordsConsumedRatePerSec()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("0.0") && !consumerMetrics.getTotalRecordsConsumed().equalsIgnoreCase("0.0")) {
            consumerMetricsList.add(consumerMetrics);
        }
    });
}


private void populateAndPrintContainerMetrics(Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> metrics, ConsumerMetrics consumerMetrics) {
metrics.entrySet()
        .forEach(entry -> {
            String topLevelMaetricKey = entry.getKey();
            consumerMetrics.setConsumerId(topLevelMaetricKey);
            System.out.println("metrics map entry key is " + topLevelMaetricKey);
            entry.getValue()
                    .entrySet()
                    .forEach(innerMapEntry -> {

                        String metricKey = innerMapEntry.getKey()
                                .name();
                        String metricValue = String.valueOf(((Metric) innerMapEntry.getValue()).metricValue());
                        System.out.println(" metricKey is " + metricKey + " and metricValue is " + metricValue);

                        switch (metricKey) {
                            case "records-consumed-rate":
                                //The average number of records consumed per second
                                consumerMetrics.setRecordsConsumedRatePerSec(metricValue);
                                break;
                            case "records-consumed-total":
                                //The total number of records consumed
                                consumerMetrics.setTotalRecordsConsumed(metricValue);
                                break;
                            case "request-size-avg":
                                //The average size of requests sent
                                consumerMetrics.setRequestSizeAvg(metricValue);
                                break;
                            case "request-rate":
                                //The number of requests sent per second
                                consumerMetrics.setRequestRate(metricValue);
                                break;
                            case "request-total":
                                //The total number of requests sent
                                consumerMetrics.setRequestTotal(metricValue);
                                break;
                            case "fetch-rate":
                                //The number of fetch requests per second
                                consumerMetrics.setFetchRate(metricValue);
                                break;

                            case "fetch-total":
                                //The total number of fetch requests
                                consumerMetrics.setFetchTotal(metricValue);
                                break;
                            case "fetch-latency-max":
                                //The max time taken for any fetch request
                                consumerMetrics.setFetchLatencyMax(metricValue);
                                break;
                            case "records-per-request-avg":
                                //The average number of records in each request for a topic
                                consumerMetrics.setRecordsPerRequestAvg(metricValue);
                                break;
                            case "assigned-partitions":
                                //The number of partitions currently assigned to this consumer
                                consumerMetrics.setAssignedPartitions(metricValue);
                                break;
                            case "records-lag-max":
                                //The max lag of the partitio
                                consumerMetrics.setRecordsLagMax(metricValue);
                                break;
                        }
                    });

        });
}
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

> The idea behind this requirement is to see if we can evenly distribute the message consumption across all the consumer threads/instances when using concurrency.

It's an unusual use case; distribution of records is normally handled on the producer side, by the partitioner.

That said, you can use a `ThreadLocal<AtomicInteger>` to keep track of the record count.

You can pause/stop the individual containers as I described [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364054/how-to-pause-a-specific-kafka-consumer-thread-when-concurrency-is-set-to-more-th/62390585#62390585).

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it is completely unreadable - edit the question instead; delete these comments and add a commend that you have added code to the question.